# Generalized Likelihood Ratio Test and Hypothesis Testing

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Below is a question from a review sheet on an upcoming final that I am really struggling with. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Let $Y_1, Y_2,...,Y_8$ be a random sample from the uniform distribution $f(y; \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} 0 \leq y \leq \theta$. Let $H_0 : \theta =2$ versus $H_1: \theta <2$. For $n=8$ and $10$% significance level show that the GLRT test is equivalent to rejecting $H_0$ in favor of $H_1$ when $Y_{max} \leq 1.5$.

Comment: If the null hypothesis $\theta=2$ is true, the probability that all $8$ observations are $1.5$ or less is $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^8 \approx 0.1$

Comment: what part are you having trouble with, the form of the test or the significance level calculation ?